# IN句の中でWITH句を使うことはできるのか

Tags: postgresql

下記SQLのようにIN句の中にWITH句を入れることは可能なのでしょうか。

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id IN (
  WITH _t2 AS (SELECT id FROM t2 WHERE id > 1)
  SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE id1 IN (SELECT id FROM _t2)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

IN区の中にはselect区の様なデータを出力するものが入ります、ですのでWITH区でもデータが
出力される様に書かれていれば、問題はありません。UPDATEで終了するとだめです。同様にINSERT,DELETEも。

XX IN (...）の場合のselectの項目は１つです。複数の選択をする場合は、（XX,YY) IN (...)の様に書く事ができます。ですのでSELECT ＊ FROM　t1　の部分は1つで有る必要があります。

`SELECT id1 FROM t1 WHERE id1 IN (SELECT id FROM _t2)`とすれば可能だと思います。

Comment: 「WITH句を使えるか？」という質問に対して、`使える`、`使えない`ではなく`使わなくても出来る`というのは質問者さんの望んでいる回答なのでしょうか？

Comment: 提示されたSQLで問題が有るとすれば、SELECT * FROM t1の部分のみなので、もしかしたらと思いお答えしました。テーブルT1の項目が１つノミであれば問題は無いです。

Comment: もしそうだとしても、質問主題から逸れてしまうので「使えるけどこうした方が良い」や「使えないのでこうした方が良い」など、主題に対する回答も添えた方がいいです。

Comment: 実行されて、エラーになった事を前提にご質問が作成されたと、想定しています。（複雑ではないので）。ご質問者様は、見ただけでお判りと思いますが、お答えの方法が良くないと言うご指摘でなので改善いたします。